# distributionmanagement maven multi-module project

Tags: maven, artifactory

We have a multi-module project based on Maven. Currently, for jar to be published to artifactory, distributionmanagement needs to be added to parent Pom and also ALL the modules' pom files.

Is there a way I can specify only in single module which I want to be published?

Comment: Why not just put it into the parent POM? The modules inherit it automatically.

Answer (score 0):

It is enough to provide `distributionManagement` in parent or root pom in your project.

If you want to skip deployment of specific module, you must skip `deploy plugin` (or other used for deployment) in this module.